# Como pegar uma semana para trás a partir do dia de hoje no Postgress

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando fazer um select para pegar uma semana para trás a partir do dia de hoje.
Isso foi oque eu já fiz alguma ideia?

```
select count(id) as total, (current_date - interval '7') as testando, extract(day from data_cadastro) as date_part,extract(month from data_cadastro) as date_part_month
from ris_atendimento as a
group by 
    extract(day from data_cadastro), extract(month from data_cadastro)  
order by 
    date_part asc;
```

Comment: Já tentou usar (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '7 DAYS'), ao invés de apenas (current_date - interval '7')?

Comment: Se você quer pegar apenas "uma semana para trás a partir do dia de hoje" então precisa colocar tal condição no WHERE.

Comment: explique melhor exatamente o que pretende e o resultado esperado basicamente os 7 dias ficaria apenas assim: ``select 
count(id) as total,
(current_date - interval '7 days') as testando
from ris_atendimento as a`` de resto tente complementar.